# windows desktop notification

Tags: winforms, notifications, desktop

we want to build an application (c#/.Net) for the following Scenario:

- internal "alert System". Users should be informed about it-system outage, planned downtime for Services and so on.
- only one-way : central Service will push Messages to user
- we also Need the possibility to enable/disable a message, for example:
  The message "there a Problems with mail System" should be removed from every Computer after the Problem is solved
- we want to shedule Messages for planned maintanance
- about 1000 windows Clients, we also want to "group" this Clients, so we can control which Client will get a message

First thought was writing small application which will query every X seconds a  central database for new and existing Messages.

Maybe somebody has already worked on similar Project? 
Is a Client with database query a way to go? Better to use other Technology, like WCF Service?

Thanks for your help

Marc

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need an enhanced version of push notifications.
I'd suggest using push for all the messaging, it's delivered faster and I find it more reliable. Simply make the client connect to a message server and maintain the connection open. Whenever a message is supposed to be displayed to the client, have the server push it trough the connection (that's where the name comes from).

To group and manage the clients you could use a database, it's probably the best way to go, but the server needs to handle all the open connections, and databases can only store DATA, not virtual objects representing a connection, so the server software need to manage them in a different way.

My suggestion: Whenever the server receives an incoming client connection, it will accept and query the client computer for a ID number that will also be used to find that client's information in the database.

Then it will create a dictionary using that ID as key, and the connection as the value.
This way at the time of sending a message to a determined group, you can do in two ways:

1) You can load from the database the IDs that belong to that group, and then send the messages to them. You will have to check whether that ID exists in the dictionary's KEYS array, because it is possible that a determined client is not yet connected.

2) You can iterate of the KEYS array of dictionary, check to which group that ID is part of, and if it is the desires group, send it.

If you're dealing with a big number of clients, I suggest you use method 1.

To disable/remove a message from the client's computer, simply have the server send a special Command message that the client software interprets as "remove that message". To make this possible every non-command message must have unique IDs, so that command messages can tell the client software which message that command applies to.

Your project sounds very interesting.
I would be glad to help you by writing a library you could use, or just help you figure it out on your own if you prefer. (Free of charge, just for the experience).

Comment: Hello,thanks for your reply. Maybe there is a way to go with SignalR. http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr

Comment: SignalR does the job, but not if you need it done in a desktop application. SignalR is a way to have that functionality between a loaded page in a client's computer and the server. One example is this is when you have Facebook open and it makes a sound when you receive a chat message. It will only work if the client has that page open.